# How to define table constraint to check non empty datetime?

Tags: sql, sql-server

While creating a table how to add table level constraint so as to check that a column with datatype datetime is not empty?

Comment: NOT NULL constraint.

Comment: You can just make your column not allow nulls.

Comment: you can't insert empty `''` into a datetime field but you can insert 0 which is equal to `01.01.1900 00:00`. if you don't want that, add a check constraint `check mydatetimecol>0`

Comment: @Aツ Actually you can insert an empty string. It will do an implicit conversion and become 1900-01-01.

Comment: @SeanLange learned something, thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use something like this with `NOT NULL`:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable](
[ID] [int] NOT NULL,
[MyField] [DATETIME] NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Sir, it is a datetime datatype. Also I want to prevent empty / blank column value which (with my limited knowledge of SQL as I'm a beginer) is not same as 'NOT NULL'

Comment: I don't know sql-server, but if it allows an empty string or whitespace characters (which is indeed not the same es null) to be inserted in a date-type-column: throw it away ;)

Comment: @Lalu -- My apologies, I was just giving you an example.  I can change the example data type to `DATETIME` if you like.  `DATETIME` does not allow "blank" or "empty" values, just `NULL` if the option is not set to `NOT NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

The NOT NULL constraint enforces a column to NOT accept NULL values.

The NOT NULL constraint enforces a field to always contain a value. This means that you cannot insert a new record, or update a record without adding a value to this field.

The following SQL enforces the "P_Id" column and the "LastName" column to not accept NULL values:

```
CREATE TABLE PersonsNotNull
(
P_Id int NOT NULL,
LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255)
)
```

Comment: Sir, CREATE TABLE PersonsNotNull
(
P_Id int NOT NULL,
LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255), constraint CK_PersonsNotNull_FirstName check (rtrim(ltrim([PersonsNotNull])) <> '')
)  will not allow empty / blank value in PersonsNotNull which has datatype varchar. My question is for a column which is of datatype DATETIME.

Answer (score 0):

If the date field has a point beyond which you know there will be no valid dates, you can set that as a lower boundary.

```
Date_Field date check( Date_Field > '2000-01-01' ),
```

If it is peoples birthdate, you will have to set it back to a more reasonable value. Now, now matter how the date is entered or what is is converted from, it must be within a reasonable range to be considered valid.